# redirecting with mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The below rule I took from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/remove-file-extention-from-urls/) and modified it (very little) so it adds a slash after removing the php file extension.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

So the url **Domain.com/file.php** will look like **Domain.com/file/**

And it works fine as long as I have a link or type in directly **Domain.com/file/** but I want to keep all my links to my php files. So I want it to redirect someone to **Domain.com/file/** if someone goes to **Domain.com/file.php**

But when I try to redirect (if I'm doing this properly)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

But It doesn't redirect. :(

I'm not sure if I'm redirecting in correctly or if I'm simply not allowed to do this. Any advice is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how it works with htaccess, but you could always just use php.
Make this a file and include it at the top of all your pages:

```
<?php    
  $page = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
  if(substr($page, -4)=='.php'){
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
      $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    }
    header( "Location: $pageURL/" + substr($page, 0, -4)  );
  }
?>
```

EDIT: If you don't care about what the user sees in the address bar, just add an [R] (try taking away the =301,L part)

Comment: Thanks for answering!... But I would really like to use .htaccess because then I will not have to edit every file (that's the only reason I want to redirect or I might as well change all my links)

Comment: It doesn't work (I tried that before I used R=301,L) and just tried it again.